# Ruby Action Cable for nested form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I have two models: post and comment, second one is nested in the first. I want to create an action cable for the comments. Here is how I made it for the posts: it works perfectly fine - showing up in console both title of the post and content. The route:

```
   resources :posts do
    resources :comments 
  end
  root "posts#index"
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

Posts controller:

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :update, :edit, :destroy]
after_action :publish_post, only: [:create]
  def publish_post
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "posts_channel", {title: @post.title, content: @post.content}
  end
private
  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Code for posts_channel.rb :

```
class PostsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "posts_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

And code for posts_channel.js :

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("PostsChannel", {
  connected() {
    console.log('i am post')
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },
  received(data) {
    console.log(data)
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  }
});
```

Very similar code I have for comments, here is comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy]
after_action :publish_comment, only: [:create]
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :comment, :user_id, :best, :file))
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
  def publish_comment
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "comments_channel", {title: @comment.name, content: @comment.comment}
  end

  private

  def find_comment
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

comments_channel.rb is the very same but streaming to comments_channel.js, here is js channel:

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("CommentsChannel", {
  connected() {
    console.log('I am comment')
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log(data)
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  }
});
```

What may be wrong with my code? I am sure, that I've done something wrong with JS code and it just cannot see the nested forms that I created on posts. As I said - both posts and comments channels are very identical but data about created post is broadcasting to my console but my comments is not, even if I defined in controller which post and which comment system should see.

Comment: i guess the cause is after a comment is created -> redirect_to post page immediately so the post page be loaded that mean the comment subscriptions is re-created, but after_action `publish_comment` is called before the comment channel is created so that the comment channel will not receive the data.

Comment: You are right, when I create comment - the post page is refreshing. So is there any way to make this work? Or do I need to add Ajax to comments so the page would not refresh? (Also the def 'publish_post' also has attribute 'after_action' but for some reason it's working)

Comment: i think your code is ok since i guess your purpose is to broadcast the new comment, right ? now suppose you and me open this post (this question) and i go to create-comment-page to create a comment, if success i will go back the post page (reload) and obviously i will see the comment, now in your side, you stay at post page and the comment channel is already created so obviously you will also receive the broadcast data. you need to open 2 tabs (or browsers) to check that.

Comment: I've tried to do it. I have two different browsers and tested the posts, they working perfectly fine - ApplicationCable broadcasted new post to my second browser but I do not understand - why it does not work for comments, if it would broadcast everything correctly - it would at least send comment data to console but I get nothing. If you want - I can send you github project.

Comment: Yes, as it was written in code. Also if it would useful to you - it was take from console before my actions: 
CommentsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
CommentsChannel is streaming from comments:comments_channel
PostsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
PostsChannel is streaming from posts_channel

Comment: in the second browser, did you see `'I am comment'` on web console ? to make sure that the comment channel is created

Comment: Yes, I can see it.

Comment: As I said - maybe I should somehow refer comments via posts? But I don't know how to do it through JS.

Comment: Also when I try to send message to my comments_channel via ruby console - for some reason I do not receive it but for posts_channel I got it.

Comment: You're also falling in the classic noob trap of calling `@post.comments.create` without checking if it actually was successful. Invalid user input is a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it. I decided to create new channel for a single post, that will be determined by id. So here is my post_channel.rb (! not a postS_channel.rb):

```
 class PostChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "post_channel_#{params[:post_id]}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Js file for post_channel:

```
 import consumer from "./consumer"

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {

  const element = document.getElementById('post-id');
  const post_id = element.getAttribute('data-post-id');

  consumer.subscriptions.create({channel: "PostChannel", post_id: post_id }, {
    connected() {
      console.log("connected to post №" + post_id)
    },

    disconnected() {
      // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
    },

    received(data) {
      $('#comment_name').append('<div class="comment"> <strong>' + data.title + '</strong></div>')
      $('#comment_content').append('<div class="comment">' + data.content + '</div>')
      console.log(data)
    }
  });
})
```

My comments_controller part:

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_comment, only: [:destroy]
  after_action :publish_comment, only: [:create]

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :comment, :user_id, :best, :file))
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def publish_comment
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("post_channel_#{@comment.post_id}", {title: @comment.name, content: @comment.comment})
  end
  private

  def find_comment
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @post_id = @post[:post_id]
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Also I added this line to my routes:

```
 get '/posts/:id' => 'posts#show'
```

So all I had to do is just to specify which post my code should broadcast to see the comments. And if someone would like to use my code - be careful, it produces new bug by which you can get 'no Post with id=['new']' error.